# Как завершить вызов Android?

Tags: java, android

Вот так я позвонил по указанному номеру:

```
Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "123456789"));
startActivity(dialIntent);
```

Есть ли способ сбросить вызов, спустя, например, 2 секунды после звонка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запускаем так:

```
Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "123456789"));
startActivityForResult(dialIntent, requestCode);  //requestCode - более-менее любой целый идентификатор
```

Останавливаем так:

```
finishActivity(requestCode);
```

Безусловно `finishActivity()` надо обернуть в отдельный поток, который через 2 секунды вызовет `finishActivity()`

Comment: прошу прощения, не совсем понял что такое requestCode. Переменная?

Comment: Вы принципиально не читаете [документацию](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))?